# Slow jobs on Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, sidekiq

In my application I have a job which makes several database queries (mysql) to recalculate certain fields of a model. (A kind of counter_caches).

Launching individually these methods take about 10 seconds to finish, but when done by sidekiq take about 180 seconds.

The current configuration is a concurrence of 20 and the configuration of the pool in the database.yml is also 20.

I tried adding another instance of sidekiq, and the times are kept around 180 sec, but of course, twice as many jobs are executed simultaneously.

Is there anything I'm not considering? Is it normal for this to happen?

Comment: By Launching individually, you mean executing only one of the blocks of code that connect to the database? When multiple connections are attempted, there might be some locking of the database to guarantee consistency, and since there are multiple queries being done by multiple workers, they all will make each other slower. This is merely a theory. Can you check how much time the processing takes, when you have concurrency set to one? (that is, only one worker at any given time)

Comment: I have done a test with only 9 requests, with a concurrence of 1, each request. 4 sec. with the concurrence of 20 each 32 - 33 sec.